# Buy 2 products with fixed price

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I need to create the following rule on my **Magento 1.8** store.

The customer can buy any 2 products from a specific category with a fixed price.

I mean if **product 1 price is 100 and product 2 price is 200** and if he added them to cart with quantity 1 to each of the final prices will be for example 250.

Also to all products in this category if the customer bought any **2 of the items**, the **final price will be 250**.

Answer (score 1):

We have this kind of requirements before and as far as I know, this isn't possible out of the box in Magento Community Edition. You need to write scripts and modify the `SalesRules`.

I suggest that you try [Amasty Special Promotions Pro](https://goo.gl/GHaZhF) or any Extensions that offer extended promotions. I've used the Amasty Promotions Pro before and it offers lots of options, but not sure if it offers this kind of instance. Might be worth giving this a try before you spend writing script.

**Edited:**

See our promotion configurations below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The output:

[image]